# Where does calling Heaven "My True Country" come from?

Tags: cs-lewis

I was reading C.S. Lewis' *Mere Christianity* yesterday; in the chapter on Hope, Lewis refers to Heaven and his ["True Country"](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/462154-the-christian-says-creatures-are-not-born-with-desires-unless).  Perhaps it's a coincidence, but there's a [Newsboys song](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/newsboys/hallelujah105312.html) with that as a lyric.  Is that a Biblical reference or does it start with C.S. Lewis or is it just a Protestant meme?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure, but it may be a reference to Hebrews 11:

> 13 All these people were still living by faith when they died. They
>   did not receive the things promised; they only saw them and welcomed
>   them from a distance, admitting that they were foreigners and
>   strangers on earth. 14 People who say such things show that they are
>   looking for a country of their own. 15 If they had been thinking of
>   the country they had left, they would have had opportunity to return.
>   16 Instead, they were longing for a **better country**—a heavenly one.
>   Therefore God is not ashamed to be called their God, for he has
>   prepared a city for them.

Also, Philippians 3:

> 20 But **our citizenship is in heaven**. And we eagerly await a Savior
>   from there, the Lord Jesus Christ, 21 who, by the power that enables
>   him to bring everything under his control, will transform our lowly
>   bodies so that they will be like his glorious body.

For reference, I believe this is the C. S. Lewis quote you are referring to:

> “The Christian says, 'Creatures are not born with desires unless
>   satisfaction for those desires exists. A baby feels hunger: well,
>   there is such a thing as food. A duckling wants to swim: well, there
>   is such a thing as water. Men feel sexual desire: well, there is such
>   a thing as sex. If I find in myself a desire which no experience in
>   this world can satisfy, the most probable explanation is that I was
>   made for another world. If none of my earthly pleasures satisfy it,
>   that does not prove that the universe is a fraud. Probably earthly
>   pleasures were never meant to satisfy it, but only to arouse it, to
>   suggest the real thing. If that is so, I must take care, on the one
>   hand, never to despise, or to be unthankful for, these earthly
>   blessings, and on the other, never to mistake them for the something
>   else of which they are only a kind of copy, or echo, or mirage. I must
>   keep alive in myself the desire for my true country, which I shall not
>   find till after death; I must never let it get snowed under or turned
>   aside; I must make it the main object of life to press on to that
>   country and to help others to do the same.”